# Modify transaxle tip to have splines instead of key slot

Tags: key, axle, fastener, nut

The car I'm rebuilding, an old Skoda Estelle with rear mounted engine, have transmissions axles that uses a key to secure the wheel hub. Its tip is conical, as the hub whole. The problem is that it uses only one key, and it eventually gets loose quite often, obviously damaging both the key and the hub.

My idea is to make new hubs but use multiple splines instead of a key. So it will be the same axles, fill the key slot by welding, lathe the conical section again and add splines to it, V splines like those in CV joints. My question is: adding splines would make the axle tip weak and more prone to break?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What would be holding the spliced section to the hub? You have to inverse the splines on the inside of the hub for it to work without slipping.

Comment: I would serrate down the axle for V "female" splines and have the hubs made with "male" splines. My only concern is about if it would weaken the axle tip, although I guess adding splines also works as for stress relieving? I would use splines like those found in CV joints: not too deep, many of them. Any good?

Answer (score 1):

Coarse splines like in your image will weaken the shaft, although it's very well possible that it'll still be strong enough. But i wouldn't take that risk either. But you can use much finer splines like you already commented, then they don't have to be very deep. If you do it like this, or even finer, the strength of the shaft will barely be compromised: [image]
It's not possible to do that yourself without advanced equipment, but you can take it to a machine shop and ask if they can do it for you.

Comment: Yes, correct, I will send the axles to a milling shop. Do you have any suggestions about how deep they should be? 3mm?

Comment: @AramAlvarez Depends on the size of the shaft and what is possible for the milling shop. They have to do the same thing with the hub, which i think is a lot harder to do. Less deep will probably be easier. I'd take 1.5mm as target.